# Network Policy in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I am connecting Nodejs app with mongodb using kubernetes cluster. I want to ensure that mongo POD communicates only with Nodejs POD and deny any other POD traffic. When I apply the default deny policy and then apply the allow policy by app is not working.

I have come up with the following policies - why are they not working?

Default Deny Policy:

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: default-deny
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels: {}
```

Network Policy:

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: access-nodejs
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nodejs-mongo
  ingress:
    - from:
      - podSelector:
          matchLabels:
            run: mongo
```

Comment: Did you forget to ask question? Also in your case it looks like you're allowing Mongo to connect to Nodejs while i suspect that it should be reverse, right?

Comment: Yeah right, other then that change does my policy looks okay? I was thinking rather then `app: nodejs` Is there any way to specify network policy on pod, so that mongo POD can only communicate with nodejs POD?

Comment: @VasiliAngapov when I apply the default deny policy I am unable to access the app so that means my allow-access network policy is not working, can you help me on this?

Comment: Please post you whole manifests and also apply the change to your default deny policy from below answer.

Answer (score 1):

I applied your policies and it worked for me. However, you don't have to specify deny-all policy. Once you create a Network Policy that allows pod to accept traffic **from** a specific set of pods it will be restricted by it. This way it will keep your setup simpler and will require less troubleshooting.

So in your case you can create a Network Policy that allows communication from a specific pod. Make sure you are using correct labels to select targeted pod(s) and pod(s) that it can accept traffic from.

Keep in mind that a `NetworkPolicy` is applied to a particular Namespace and only selects Pods in that particular `Namespace`.

Example policy that can be applied to accept traffic from pods matching it's selectors:

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: backend-access
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: restricted-access #it selects pods that are targeted by this policy
  ingress:
    - from:
      - podSelector:
          matchLabels:
            app: allowed-traffic #selects pods that communicate with pods
```

Answer (score 0):

The deny all policy should look like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-ingress
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
```